# how to add more space to the left in header logo in bootstrap5?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[how header looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u5A3.png)

Hello everyone!
im trying to learn bootstrap and make a basic website for practise.
but i cant add more space to the left header logo. I tried different things one of them was giving img a margin in css.stylesheet.
it did change but i dont want all images to have margin.
I tried adding id, it didnt work.
And aside from this example how can i very specifically position any bootstrap code?
Its shameful but im stuck, its been nearly 3 hours..Thank you all in advance.

edit:i just added button part mt-10 and the logo's position changed... im even more confused
'''html

```
     <button
      class="navbar-toggler mt-10 "
      type="button"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
      aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    > '''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you share your code.

My guess is use class="ms-5" (margin start).

Bootstrap 5 changed from "Margin left" to "Margin Start" on the new version.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand **ADD HERE -> (ms-1 to ms-5)**" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I hope that fixes your issue.
Good luck!

Comment: I found another solution, and sharing this in case anyone needs it; if you give .navbar ml-5 and then add in css stylesheet ''' .ml-5 {
  margin-left: 10% !important;
}''' you can adjust it however you like. i cant figure out why but you must name your class as mr-* or it won't work.